# How to know the inviter of the bot ? discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to know who is the inviter of the bot but I don't find anything on the documentation or on forum. 
If someone has an idea :/

Comment: I don't think this is part of the bot API, although you could look into using [Discord OAuth2](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) of which you could get user information from, and then let them invite the bot.

Comment: The Discord API doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT

Recently discord added an entry in guild audit logs that log everytime someone adds a bot into the server, so you can use it to know who added the bot.
Example:

```js
// client needs to be instance of Discord.Client
// Listen to guildCreate event
client.on("guildCreate", async guild => {
    // Fetch audit logs
    const logs = await guild.fetchAuditLogs()
    // Find a BOT_ADD log
    const log = logs.entries.find(l => l.action === "BOT_ADD" && l.target.id === client.user.id)
    // If the log exits, send message to it's executor
    if(log) log.executor.send("Thanks for adding the bot")
})
```

---

#### Old Anwser

The discord API doesn't allow this.

But, you can send a message to the Owner of the guild using the property `guild.owner` to get it

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
       guild.owner.send('Message here').catch(e => {
              // Can't message to this user
       })
})
```